# For loop in postgres requires a FROM clause when parameter is passed though function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_looper(p_array bigint[])

...

                    for indx in 1.. p_array.count BY 1
                      loop                               
                        select code into object_code
                         from myTable
                           where myTable_id =  p_array(indx);
   

...
```

however I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "p_array"
LINE 1: SELECT p_array.count
```

This value is passed into the function as a parameter, its not a table so unsure why this is complaining. what have i done wrong?

Comment: Why a for loop to begin with? you could just use `where id = any(p_array)`?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) you access an array element through square brackets: `p_array[indx]`

Comment: i changed it to where id = any(p_array) but its still complaining about the from clause

Comment: Look at the error message, it is complaining about this:`for indx in 1.. p_array.count`. See here [Array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html). Pretty sure you are looking for `array_length` e.g. `array_length(p_array, 1)`.

Comment: If you really need the slow and inefficient loop, use [foreach](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) to iterate over the array